# Jira API bulk create - create all or none

Tags: api, jira, jira-rest-api, bulk

I want to create multiple issues at once using `/rest/api/2/issue/bulk` endpoint.

However, I want it to fail if ANY of the tickets fail. Right now it creates tickets that are correct, but my preferred way is to block it from adding any ticket if at least one fails.

Is there a way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the response from the server is an error message (IE the request failed) why not use that as the point to stop processing any more requests?